# How can I associate datarows from datatestmethod with separate tests in Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vstest

I have a method marked with attribute [DataTestMethod] and several [DataRow] attributes on the same method like so:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[TestCategory("MyCategory")]
[DataRow("Input1")]
[DataRow("Input2")]
[DataRow("Input3")]
public void MyDataTest(string input)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

This shows up as 3 separate tests in the test explorer window of Visual Studio. How can I properly associate these to 3 separate tests in Azure test manager? Adding association simply sets the test to "Assembly.Namespace.Class.MyDataTest" with no indication as to which datarow is to be used. This results in only the first row (Input1) being executed in my release pipeline. Is there a way to associate to specific data rows, or do I need to explicitly write out separate methods for each row?
Note: running `vstest.console /listtests:mytests.dll` generates a list with 3 tests in it:

```
The following Tests are available:
    MyDataTest (Input1)
    MyDataTest (Input2)
    MyDataTest (Input3)
```

But I can't seem to get azure pipelines to run all 3 tests.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this?  I'm having the same problem!

Comment: Alas no. I ended up splitting all data test methods into separate methods (you can still use the DataTestMethod attribute, even if there is only one single DataRow), each with exactly one DataRow. A bit cumbersome, but it's the only way I found to get each variation to run through an Azure pipeline stage. FWIW, I also pulled out the code from the test method and made that a separate helper which is then called by each test method. Good luck!

Comment: Alternatively, you could try running the test task by Assembly (instead of by test run or test suite), as like mentioned above, each data row gets discovered as a test by vstest.console. Unfortunately, if you run by Assembly, you will lose the ability to associate test methods with Azure Test Cases (and all the nice tracking/charts that come with that).